# Convert a range to a percentage in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a range of figures I want to convert to percentage.

For example I have temperature readings taken every hour over a full day. The range is from 4.5deg to 15.5deg. I want 4.5deg to equal 0% and 15.5deg to equal 100%.

I want to automatically display all other temperature readings during the day as a %.

For example 10deg would be displayed as 50%

Comment: What have you tried so far and are the minimum and maximum predetermined, or are you additionally seeking for the minimum and maximum value of a given range as well?

Comment: I haven't tried much to be honest as I don't know where to start. I am looking to display the full list of temperture differences and have an extra column next to it to show what percentage it is compared to the min and max value.

Comment: What is the mathematical formula that would be able to calculate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your temperatures are in column A, you can put this in cell `B1` and drag it down

```
=(A1-MIN(A:A))/(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))
```

Change the format of those cells to percentage and baby, you got stew going!

Comment: Super, just needed to add the $ signs for the min and max and worked a treat.

Comment: @AdrianMac if this solves the question, please click the green checkmark to indicate it has been solved.